# How to compare a string to the different arguments of an object in a array of object?

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, object, compare

I have an array of object **Contact**. Each **Contact** has 3 arguments:

- Id
- Name
- Function

I'm creating that array in that function:

```
public ActionResult AutocompleteCollabo(string term)
    {
        int NumDossier = StructureData.DonneNumDossier((string)Session["NumCRPCEN"], (string)Session["MotDePasse"]);
        List<Contact> ListeContacts = StructureData.DonneListeElementDossier(NumDossier);
        Contact[] tabContacts = new Contact[ListeContacts.Count()];
        int count = 0;
        foreach (Contact contact in ListeContacts)
        {
            tabContacts[count] = contact;
            count++;
        }
        var collaborateurs = tabContacts;

        var filteredItems = collaborateurs.Where(
            item => item.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
            );
        return Json(filteredItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now I would like to compare the string **term** entered as a parameter in the function to
the **name** and the **function** of each object of the array. As the array is a one of objects I can't use **indexOf**. Does anybody have a solution to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) on the Contact object itself since your're using Linq. Assuming both name and function are strings.

```
var filteredItems = collaborateurs.Where(
            item => item.Name.Contains(term) || item.Name.Function.Contains(term)
            );
```